# Contentful ignoring proxy configuration

Tags: proxy, contentful

I'm trying to setup a proxy to Contentful Delivery SDK to intercept the response and add relevant data. For development purposes, the proxy is still running locally. This is the configuration I'm using right now:

```
const client = createClient({
  space: SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,
  host: CDN_URL,
  environment: ENVIRONMENT,
  basePath: 'api',
  retryOnError: false,
  proxy: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    auth: {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password',
    },
  },
});
```

For some reason, this `client` keeps ignoring the `proxy` settings, making the request directly to Contentful CDN. I tried removing the host field from the configuration, but it didn't change the outcome. I also tried using the `httpsAgent` configuration with [`HttpsProxyAgent`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent) instead of the `proxy` one, but also didn't work.

Versions:

- "contentful": "^7.11.3"
- "react": "^16.13.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the proxy configuration cannot be used client-side. It's unclear if that is your use case here.

There is a known bug [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2072). Either try installing a newer version of Axios, which is the lib that the contentful SDK uses. Or use a proxyAgent:

```js
const HttpProxyAgent = require("http-proxy-agent");
const httpAgent = new HttpProxyAgent({host: "proxyhost", port: "proxyport", auth: "username:password"})
```

Now just pass the agent into the create client method:

```
const client = createClient({
    ....
    httpAgent: httpAgent,
    ....
});
```

Comment: Note, you used the HTTPS agent previously, this is HTTP.

Comment: Thanks! Proxying from client-side was indeed my use case. Didn't find anything related to this limitation on the docs, though.